# WordPress Pagination with custom post type. URL to other pages?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I'm trying to add pagination to a custom post type I have

In my template file

```
<?php //Get content
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'news',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ): 
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <!-- CONTENT -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php pagination_bar($my_query); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The Pagination  I have in my functions.php file

```
function pagination_bar($my_query) {
$total_pages = $my_query->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
    ));
}
}
```

The pagination appears to work fine on my page. It shows up and displays the right number of pages. Only when I click on a page I get a 404 error. Nothing I type in the URL gets me to a second page which is leading me to believe that there is no second page being generated?

When you limit posts_per_page, is there a default url pattern to get to the second page?

Sorry for the vagueness of the question but I'm not sure if this is a pagination issue or an issue with the setting up WordPress correctly to generate the other pages.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the permalinks structure that you are using?
Is your theme using any specific permalinks structure which you may have not select.
In your Admin Dashboard, Goto Settings > permalinks

More about permalinks:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: The permalinks were set to post name. I switched it to the numeric option and now it works like a charm. Thanks!